# URLSession GET request fails on eduroam

Tags: swift, macos, nsurlsession

I am running into a strange error with Swift 3.

**I am trying to request a URL in a Swift application but the request always fails. I have tried opening different URLs and opening the URLs in my browser, where the requests work.**

I am using the following code snippet I found online:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/ip")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }
    guard let data = data else {
        print("Data is empty")
        return
    }

    let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    print(json)
}

task.resume()
```

This is the error my program is producing

```
2018-04-30 11:11:08.318299+0200 TokenList[2765:48745] PAC result block not invoked
2018-04-30 11:11:08.318361+0200 TokenList[2765:48745] [] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork: 308
2018-04-30 11:11:08.318380+0200 TokenList[2765:48737] Received XPC error Connection invalid for message type 3 kCFNetworkAgentXPCMessageTypePACQuery
2018-04-30 11:11:08.318880+0200 TokenList[2765:48745] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 1
2018-04-30 11:11:09.319675+0200 TokenList[2765:48745] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 2
2018-04-30 11:11:10.322336+0200 TokenList[2765:48745] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect()-> No of tries: 3
2018-04-30 11:11:11.323967+0200 TokenList[2765:48745] dnssd_clientstub ConnectToServer: connect() failed path:/var/run/mDNSResponder Socket:10 Err:-1 Errno:1 Operation not permitted
2018-04-30 11:11:11.324569+0200 TokenList[2765:48745] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_locked DNSServiceCreateDelegateConnection failed: ServiceNotRunning(-65563)
2018-04-30 11:11:11.325512+0200 TokenList[2765:48745] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x6000001630c0]: 10:-72000 Err(-65563)
2018-04-30 11:11:11.326603+0200 TokenList[2765:48737] Task <F194834F-65B5-4E6D-B088-B4947A029818>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1003 [10:-72000])
2018-04-30 11:11:11.326897+0200 TokenList[2765:48737] Task <F194834F-65B5-4E6D-B088-B4947A029818>.<1> finished with error - code: -1003
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000442250 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-72000, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=10}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://httpbin.org/ip, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://httpbin.org/ip, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=10, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-72000, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found.}
```

I am suspecting this issue could be caused by me being on eduroam, the heavily gated university wifi. On the other hand other requests (from other macOS) applications are working fine.

Additionally there should be no issues with misconfiguration on the Mac is it is brand new and only homebrew and a few programs have been installed.

I am looking forward to any pointers you might have and would like to thank you in advance.